# ¿Qué significa "-m" cuando ejecutamos un script desde la línea de comandos en Python?

Tags: python, terminal, línea-de-comandos

Cuando uso el comando `python3 -m pip install`, ¿qué significado tiene `-m`?

Comment: usa el tu terminal el comando python -h (que es para help o ayuda) y ahi tendrás en la lista de banderas la respuesta a tu pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, ya sé para qué sirve :)

Comment: Si te parece bien lo anexo como respuesta para que la puedas calificar

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Información extraída de [una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7610082/1983854) a [What is the purpose of the -m switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7610001/1983854)</sub>

La primera línea de la sección *Rationale* del [PEP 338](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/) indica:

> Python 2.4 añade el selector `-m` para línia de comandos para permitir que los módulos puedan ser buscados utilizando el namespace de módulos de Python para ejecutar scripts. Los ejemplos que lo motivan son módulos estándar de librería como `pdf` y `profile`, y la implementación de Python 2.4 está bien para este propósito limitado.

Esto quiere decir que puedes especificar cualquier módulo en la ruta de búsqueda de Python, en lugar de solamente los ficheros que están en el directorio actual.

La primera línea de *Scope of this proposal* (es decir, *Ámbito de esta propuesta*) indica:

> En Python 2.4, un módulo localizado utilizando `-m` se ejecuta de la misma manera que si el nombre del archivo se hubiera indicado por línea de comandos.

Comment: Ayúdanos a conservar la calidad de la información en el sitio, contestando preguntas que estén basadas en lo definido en el  [help], específicamente [ask]. Revisar [answer].

Comment: @Jorgesys ¿tiene este comentario algo que ver con el negativo que acabo de recibir en [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/145784/83)?